# How do I change the CSS for the sequential number element on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used jQuery to generate a sequential numbering for my menu items.

When clicked, the hyperlink text becomes red.
However, the problem here is that I want the respective number to turn into red as well when the hyperlink is clicked (active).

Such as when 'WHY YOU NEED IT' is clicked, the text turns red perfectly. But I need the number 1's background color to change into red as well.

I tried replacing classes but it didn't work.

This is the JS.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$(".menu-solutions-menus-container ul li").each(function (i, el) {  $(this).children('a').prepend("<number>" + (i + 1.) + "</number>");
});



$('.local-scroll').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var full_url = this.href;

    var parts = full_url.split('#');
    var trgt = parts[1];

    var target_offset = $('#' + trgt).offset();
    var target_top = target_offset.top;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target_top
    }, 500);


});

$('.menu-solutions-menus-container a').click(function () {
    $('.menu-solutions-menus-container a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.number').click(function () {
    $('.number').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[Here's the jsfiddle workspace. (Change jQuery version to jQuery 1.7.2 or above if you don't see the numbers.)](https://jsfiddle.net/4D3bH/456/)

[The secondary menu in this site is where I would really want to implement it.](http://www.intelligentcmo.com/cmo-marketing/)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class names just need a tweek and this'll work fine

change

```
number.active {
    background: white;
}
```

To

```
.active number {
    background: red;
}
```

Edit (explanation)

The CSS selector `number.active` is looking for an html element `number` that has a class of `active` like this `<number class="active" />` but what your HTML shows is that you wanted the parent `<a>` to have the active with a child node of `<number>`.

So to do that you put the parent class first, followed by a space to note a child node of the parent, followed by the element you want to target.

so:

```
parentElement.parentClass childElement.childClass {
    defs
}
```

you could write

```
a.active number {
    background: red
}
```

Edit 2 for top bars:

There's a few things, the first being that the grey areas are actually background colors, as opposed to borders. Second the CSS selector is looking for a parent class of "active" but your "active" is a child of the `<li>`'s

```
<li id="menu-item-205" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-205">
    <a href="#what-we-offer" class="active"></a>
</li>
```

what you can do is make the `li` the get the `active` class like this

```
$('.menu-solutions-menus-container a').click(function () {
    $('.menu-solutions-menus-container a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});

$('.number').click(function () {
    $('.number').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});


$('.menu-solutions-menus-container a').click(function(){
     $('ul.shortcode_menu.solution-menu li').removeClass('active');
     $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Then change your CSS to reflect the `<li>` is the element with the active class.

```
ul.shortcode_menu.solution-menu li.active {
    background: black;
}
```

Again I've changed it to `background: black` instead of `border-top`, as I think that's the effect you want.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks. I am not an expert in this. Would you be kind enough to give me the reason why '.active' works before 'number' for the numbers but it comes after as in '#solution a.active' for the hyperlink text element?

Comment: Thanks again. However, this method does not work when I use it for the top borders in the link of the site I mentioned earlier where I wanted them to change red as well. But the top-border does not change in color when the link is clicked. Here's the updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/4D3bH/463/. Why is that?

Comment: Yes, I did manage to merge them both and now they work perfectly in my site. Thanks a lot.